# Summing an ng-repeat inside an ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-table

Is there a way for me to sum an interior loop:

Like if I had information in this format:

```
 a : {b:[1,2,3,4,5]}
```

right now I iterate like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="group in whole">
    <td>{{group.name}}</td>
    <td ng-repeat="list in group">
         {{element.amt}}
    </td>
</tr>
```

and I want to get a total at the end of each column.

I have this solution so far:

```
$scope.$watch('data', function(newValue) {
    if (newValue !== undefined) {
        angular.forEach(newValue, function(val, key) {
            $scope.allSum=0;
            angular.forEach(val.list, function(v, k) {
                v.sum = v.value;
            });
        });
     }
}, true);
```

so I'm able to calculate the value of each individual row, but then the variable is only mapped to the last row showing.

Comment: Just show the total as a `$scope` function call like `{{getSum(group)}}`.  It will be properly updated with the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the data is structured is as follows:

```
{
    a : { b : [1,2,3,4,5] },
    c : { d : [6,7,8,9,10] },
    e : { f : [11,12,13,14,15] }
}
```

In Template:

```
        <tr>
            <td>Total: </td>
            <td>{{ getTotal() }}</td>
        </tr>
```

In Controller:

```
$scope.getTotal = function getTotal() {
    var total = 0, sum = 0;
    // iterate through the whole group -- "a,c,e" keys
    for (var obj in $scope.group) {
        // grab current element's array -- first key of the current object
        var arr = Object.keys(obj)[0];
        // utilize reduce to sum all values in array
        sum = arr.reduce(function(a,b) { return a + b; }, 0);
        // increment total
        total += sum;
    }
    return total
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write simple filter:

```
app.filter('sum', function() {
  return function(array, property) {
    var result = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      result += (property ? array[i][property] : array[i]);
    }

    return result;
  }
})
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/VVm2r1WgTnDvqhw2ub3Q?p=preview